# How to find minimum timediff between N different times and a timestamp column in 1 query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, performance, timestamp

So imagine I have a database with identifiers and a timestamp:

```
ID.      Time_Stamp_Col

id1.     2017-10-16 17:54:28
id2.     2016-09-13 17:14:17
id3.     2019-10-01 19:30:37
id4.     2017-08-27 20:55:30
id5.     2017-11-19 10:56:15
id6.     2018-02-12 09:59:24
```

and an arbitrary number of timestamps (2 for this example):

```
2018-02-12 09:55:29
2017-11-19 10:21:12
```

How do I return a column that holds the minimum timestampdiff between the Time_stamp_Col and the arbitrary number of timestamps?

(I am using python so I am totally okay making a loop to generate repetitive text to fit the arbitrary number of timestamps)

I have this so far:

```
SELECT 
    LEAST(DATEDIFF('2018-02-12 09:55:29',
                    b.Time_Stamp_Col),
            DATEDIFF('2017-11-19 10:21:12',
                    b.Time_Stamp_Col)),
FROM
    DataBaseInQuestion b
```

But it is so incredibly slow. DataBaseInQuestion has 14 million rows. Is there a faster way?

Comment: If you need to return 14 million rows, your query is going to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Find the "median timestamp range" which has minimal summary difference for given "arbitrary number of timestamps".

If the amount of "arbitrary timestamps" is odd then this is the median timestamp. Take the timestamp equal to this median. If such timestamp not exists then take any timestamp within the range of the timestamps adjacent to the median timestamp or, if no such timestamp, take the timestamp closest to this range.

If the amount of "arbitrary timestamps" is even then this is a range between two median timestamps. Take any timestamp within this range or, if no such timestamp, take the timestamp closest to this range.

In both variants "closest timestamp" means "the timestamp which has minimal amount of arbitrary timestamps between self and closest range border, if there are a couple of such timestamp then take closest by the difference".

---

We need not formula/theory but practical solution. Steps:

1. We have an array of "data timestamps". Let's say it is DTS[1..X], it contains X timestamps.
2. We have an array of "arbitrary timestamps". Let's say it is ATS[1..N], it contains N timestamps.
3. Calculate the indices of two median elements in ATS (for odd-amount array this will be the same element). N<sub>1</sub> = (N+1) MOD 2 ; N<sub>2</sub> = (N+2) MOD 2.
4. In DTS - find the timestamp DTS[K<sub>1</sub>] closest but not above ATS[N<sub>2</sub>] and the timestamp DTS[K<sub>2</sub>] closest but not below ATS[N<sub>1</sub>].
5. Calculate "summary distance" for DTS[K<sub>1</sub>] and DTS[K<sub>2</sub>].

If the sums are equal then both elements and all elements between them (yes, they may be not adjacent in this case!) are the solution.

If they differs then the element with least sum is a solution. It seems that in this case cannot be a couple of solutions (but you may test its neighbors for to ensure).

---

Why this must work?

Imagine that AST contains 2 ts only. Take one DST between them, it has some difference sum. Move it 1s left. The distance to left ATS decreases by 1s, to right - increases by 1s, and total sum is unchanged. Move one more, and again... and the sum is constant until we reach left ATS. When we cross it the sum will increase by 2 for each 1s move.

Now imagine that we have 3-element ATS. Again take one DST and put it over the middle AST. Move to left or to right by 1s - partial sum to left/right ASTs will not change, distance to middle will increase by 1s, total sum will increase by 1s. Move more - when we cross the extreme ATS the sum will increase by 3 for each step...

Expand this to 4, 5, ... element in ATS. The timestamp which has minimal sum matches the median timestamp or median timestamps range. Moving away from it increases the sum, crossing a timestamp increases increasing rate.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand /: How would this translate to the shortest time difference between the row and the arbitrary time stamps?

Comment: @Travasaurus Some explanations added.